# how to overwrite the defaul.xml after repo init

Tags: android, git, android-manifest, repo

I need to do the following steps,i need to update the default.xml to change the revision of some projects and then sync the code,is there a repo option to sync to local default.xml files?if not can you please advise how to deal with this problem?

```
1.repo init -u git://git. company.com/platform/manifest.git -b <branchname>
2.Update default.xml to change the revision of some projects

  <project path="kernel"
           name="kernel/msm"
           revision="refs/heads/3.18" /> 
3. repo sync
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to modify default.xml directly, you can put your modification in local_manifests.

For how to use local_manifest.xml, you can refer to [here](http://xda-university.com/as-a-developer/local_manifests-cookbook)